# Optimize the JS Function to filter the data based on Month

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, momentjs, datejs

Currently, I have written below function to filter the items based on the month and return in Array and I have used below login.

Can someone help is there any way I can filter even more easily using datejs or moment js using for loop in more efficient way

Here I am getting date in the format of `2/Jan/17` and filtering based on `includes` method

Thanks in advance!!

**Javascript**

```
 function getMonthlyCount() {
    return yearlyExecution()
      .then(function(myitems) {
        monthlyDataForGraph = [];
        var janFinalCount = febFinalCount = marFinalCount = aprFinalCount = mayFinalCount = junFinalCount = julFinalCount = augFinalCount = sepFinalCount = octFinalCount = novFinalCount = decFinalCount = 0;
        myitems.forEach(function(items) {
          releasename = items[0].cycleName;
          janData = $filter('filter')(items, function(inputs) {
            if (inputs.executedOn.includes("Jan/17"))
              return inputs;
          });
          febData = $filter('filter')(items, function(inputs) {
            if (inputs.executedOn.includes("Feb/17"))
              return inputs;
          });
          marData = $filter('filter')(items, function(inputs) {
            if (inputs.executedOn.includes("Mar/17"))
              return inputs;
          });
          aprData = $filter('filter')(items, function(inputs) {
            if (inputs.executedOn.includes("Apr/17"))
              return inputs;
          });
          mayData = $filter('filter')(items, function(inputs) {
            if (inputs.executedOn.includes("May/17"))
              return inputs;
          });
          junData = $filter('filter')(items, function(inputs) {
            if (inputs.executedOn.includes("Jun/17"))
              return inputs;
          });
          julData = $filter('filter')(items, function(inputs) {
            if (inputs.executedOn.includes("Jul/17"))
              return inputs;
          });
          augData = $filter('filter')(items, function(inputs) {
            if (inputs.executedOn.includes("Aug/17"))
              return inputs;
          });
          sepData = $filter('filter')(items, function(inputs) {
            if (inputs.executedOn.includes("Sep/17"))
              return inputs;
          });
          octData = $filter('filter')(items, function(inputs) {
            if (inputs.executedOn.includes("Oct/17"))
              return inputs;
          });
          novData = $filter('filter')(items, function(inputs) {
            if (inputs.executedOn.includes("Nov/17"))
              return inputs;
          });
          decData = $filter('filter')(items, function(inputs) {
            if (inputs.executedOn.includes("Dec/17"))
              return inputs;
          });
          janFinalCount = janFinalCount + janData.length;
          febFinalCount = febFinalCount + febData.length;
          marFinalCount = marFinalCount + marData.length;
          aprFinalCount = aprFinalCount + aprData.length;
          mayFinalCount = mayFinalCount + mayData.length;
          junFinalCount = junFinalCount + junData.length;
          julFinalCount = julFinalCount + julData.length;
          augFinalCount = augFinalCount + augData.length;
          sepFinalCount = sepFinalCount + sepData.length;
          octFinalCount = octFinalCount + octData.length;
          novFinalCount = novFinalCount + novData.length;
          decFinalCount = decFinalCount + decData.length;
        });
        monthlyDataForGraph = [janFinalCount, febFinalCount, marFinalCount, aprFinalCount, mayFinalCount, junFinalCount, julFinalCount, augFinalCount, sepFinalCount, octFinalCount, novFinalCount, decFinalCount];
        console.log('Monthly Data For Graph', monthlyDataForGraph);
        return monthlyDataForGraph;
      });
  }
```

Comment: You can store the values of month in array and iterate those inside your single $filter function instead of if condition many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Underscore group by](http://underscorejs.org/) with [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) something like

```
var data= _.groupBy(arr,function(item){return moment(inputs.executedOn,"DD/MMM/YY").format("MMM")})



var janData=data["Jan"] ? data["Jan"].length : 0;
```

[Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dw21g4v/)

Comment: Just slight Correction `var janData=data["Jan"] ? data["Jan"].length : 0;`

Comment: @Batman ok bro then need to change `format("MM")` to `format("MMM")`